# When to choose a remote queue design versus local queue for get/put activities

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to figure out under what conditions I would want to implement a remote queue versus a local one for 2 endpoint applications.

Consider this scenario:  App **A** on Server **A** needs to send messages to App **B** on Server **B** via MQServer1.

It seems like the simplest configuration would be to create a single local queue on MQServer1 and configure AppA to put messages to the local queue while configuring AppB to get messages from the same local queue.  Both AppA and AppB would connect to the same Queue Manager but execute different commands.

What sort of circumstances would require the need to install another MQ server (e.g. MQServer2) and configure a remote queue on MQServer1 which instead sends the messages from AppA over a channel to a local queue on MQServer2 to be consumed by AppB?

I believe I understand the benefit of remote queuing but I'm not sure when it's best used over a more simpler design.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some problems with what you call the simpler design that you don't have with remote queuing:-

- **Time Independance** - Server1 has to be available all the time, whereas with a remote queue, once the messages have been moved to Server B, Server A and Server 1 don't need to be online when App B wants to get its messages.
- **Network Efficiency** - with two client applications putting or getting from a central queue, you have two inefficient network hops, instead of one efficient channel batched network connection from Server A to Server B (no need for Server 1 in the middle)
- **Network Problems** - No network, no messages. Whereas when they are stored locally, any that have already arrived can be processed even while the network is down. Likewise, the application putting messages is also not held up by a network problem, the messages sit on the transmit queue easy to be moved, and the application can get on with the next thing.

Of course your applications should be written so that they aren't even aware of the difference, and it's just configuration changes that switch you from one design to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here we can have separate Queue Manager for both the application.Application A will send the message on to the queue defined on local Queue Manager, which in turn transmit it to the Transmission queue via defined channels (Need to do configuration for that in the QueueManager) which in turn send it to the Local queue of the Application B.